# Why there is no need to directly import ReactiveFormsModule to use FormControlDirective?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

### Problem

In my application I'm having a [`SharedModule`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module) which declares all components and directives used in multiple modules throught the whole app.

As I decided to use reactive forms (instead of template-driven forms) in all my forms throught the whole application, I decided to import [`ReactiveFormsModule`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule) in `SharedModule` to import it only once and make it available to all my [feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules). The interesting part is that I don't re-export `ReactiveFormsModule`.

**shared.module.ts**

```
(...)
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
(...)

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    (...),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    (...)
   ],

   declarations: [
     (...)
   ],

   exports: [
     // ReactiveFormsModule is not re-exported here!
     (...)
   ],
}
export class SharedModule {}
```

In my app I have a `UsersModule` which imports `SharedModule` and declares `UsersAddComponent`:

**users.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    UsersRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    UsersRootComponent,
    UsersAddComponent,
    UsersIndexComponent,
  ],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

**users-add.component.html**

```
(...)
<!-- Name -->
<npc-form-control-text
  [label]="'name' | translate"
  [formControl]="name"
>
</npc-form-control-text>
(...)
```

It works. And that surprises me! Quoting [Angular NgModules documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-api):

> Declarations are private by default. If this module does not export
>   UserComponent, then only the components within this module can use
>   UserComponent.
>
> Importing a module does not automatically re-export the imported
>   module's imports. Module 'B' can't use ngIf just because it imported
>   module 'A' which imported CommonModule. Module 'B' must import
>   CommonModule itself.

So as `UsersModule` doesn't import `ReactiveFormsModule` directly - it only imports `SharedModule` which imports `ReactiveFormsModule` but does not export it - it shouldn't have access to [`FormControlDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective). But it does, it all works. And as soon as I remove `ReactiveFormsModule` from `SharedModule` imports array, it stops working producing error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
  <input
    [type]="type"
    [ERROR ->][formControl]="formControl"
    class="FormControl-input"
  />
"): ng:///SharedModule/FormControlTextComponent.html@10:4
```

### Question

Why I don't need to re-export `ReactiveFormsModules` in `SharedModule` for `UsersModule` components being able to use `FormControlDirective`?

Comment: Good spot! My overlook :). Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular always shows a hint of what is going on:

```
ng:///SharedModule/FormControlTextComponent.html@10:4
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As we can see your `FormControlTextComponent` is declared in `SharedModule` and that's why removing `ReactiveFormsModule` from `SharedModule` breaks this component.